# Network share (avahi broadcasted) not listed under Locations in MacOS Finder

Tags: ubuntu, debian, samba, network-share, avahi

I have two servers. One ubuntu (jammy), the other debian (buster) both running samba shares. If I configure "fruit:model" in smb.conf, the network share appears in finder but the icon under Locations (left window pane) shows a default icon. So, enter avahi.

Installed avahi on both servers. Both avahi-daemon instances are configured identically.

Here is /etc/avahi/services/smb.service, configured on both servers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
    <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h</name>
    <service>
        <type>_smb._tcp</type>
        <port>445</port>
    </service>
    <service>
        <type>_device-info._tcp</type>
        <port>0</port>
        <txt-record>model=MacPro7,1</txt-record>
    </service>
</service-group>
```

Here's the issue. When i mount a share on 'orion', the network share appears under Location in Finder. This is not the case with 'stardust'. (see image)

[finder screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD4Hx.png)

Not sure what the issue could be. Any pointers appreciated.